# Storing data locally in browser-based apps on Android and iOS

Tags: html, mobile, web

I'm trying to create a browser based app that does not (and can not) send data over the internet. I need it to store data locally until I am back in my office and then dump that data to a central database via wifi. I'm trying to find a cross platform web server that will run on Android and IOS so I can use my app on tablets.

Is there something like this that exists or is there a better way to accomplish my task?

Thanks.

Comment: You are in control of what your browser based app sends over the internet. If you want it to only store locally, then program it to do so. Build an export feature to dump in whatever format you need. If you don't know how to do this, hire someone who does. The "webserver" is irrelevant to what it sounds like you need

Comment: I wonder why this question has so few votes, this would be something extremely useful to handle situations where a user needs to use a site when offline.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using IndexedDB, but as far as mobile devices go only Chrome on Android, Firefox on Android, and BlackBerry browser support it.

Therefore, you can use [Web Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) (also known as local storage) to store the in the browser, then send the data upon clicking a button or some other action.

With native apps you can use SQLite databases and [such](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) (at least for Android), but it's pretty limited as far as browser-based apps go.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is HTML5's `Web Storage`. W3C has a good tutorial of the API [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). This solution should work on mobile browsers.

Comment: Are you sure? I always thought their tutorials were hosted here. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/w3c/). You are right that it is not the W3C spec but the tutorial should be more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. They sound close to what I'm looking for and I'll look into them, but just to offer a little more clarity; I need to share the data among several people. So I need each user to be able to both send and retrieve data from a local database. When each user gets back to the office, he sync's with the central database and gets back what everyone else has been doing. So each user is carrying around a complete set of the data (after sync'ing). So I'm not just "storing" data temporarily, I am actively updating the database and retrieving data from it.

Comment: I'm 100% sure. W3C tutorials and documentation are hosted at [Web Platform Docs](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/Main_Page), but it's pretty new and severely lacking at some areas. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740473) are pretty comprehensive, and more importantly, *accurate*. See [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource.

Answer (score 0):

A "Browser-based" app inherently needs to connect to a server (the host of the app, unless it is localhost) unless you are caching/hosting the app files on the device as well using web storage. I think you can do this on Android but I'm not sure about iPhone without a jailbreak.

I think the best way to be would be to create individual front ends for your devices using a multiplatform SDK, using a shared database languages (both android and iOS support SQLite) That talk to the server whenever it is available.

Keep in mind you will also have to account for the inevitable sync issues.